# Periodical request

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, browser

I need to check body of page through GET request every 30 seconds, and if I find form in DOM i need to submit it. I think this can be easily done in JS.

My question is how to check content of page in some period? Maybe set browser to automatic reload page with my JavaScript in some interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading the page will be very inconvenient for any users browsing the page.

You can have an interval function running, checking if the form you are looking for exists. Check out these links for its usage:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Or, you could use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect when the form is added to the page.

Comment: Reloading whole page is not a problem here, it will run just on my localhost. I dont know how to write that kind of internal function. This observer is interesting, i take clooser look at it, if it will work i accept answer.

Comment: If you do not know how to set up an interval function, then the Mutation Observer is probably too advanced for you. You can see the usage of interval in the following links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: I dont know javascript too much, but i know observer from another language. Thanks, i can definitely make it now with this interval function example.